# XPATH in difficult span - Scrapy

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I use Scrapy and write script based on XPATH selector. I try search XPATH syntax to collect two value: price and EAN number (500.02, 08043687312822). Price: 500,2 and EAN: 08043687312822

```
<div class="emProductPrice">
  <span itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://example.com/Offer">
    <span 
itemprop="price" content="500.02">500,02</span>&nbsp;hrywna<meta itempr\
op="priceCurrency" content="PLN">
    <meta itemprop="gtin14" 
content="08043687312822">
    <link itemprop="itemCondition" 
href="http://example.com/NewCondition">
    <l\ink itemprop="availability" href="http://example.com/InStock">
  </span> 
</div>
```

I try write syntax something like: `//div[@class="emProductPrice"/span/span/text()` but i get only: &nbsp. I need 500,02 for example

How do this? Please help.

Comment: Hey @pali112, Do you have example code or something that you have tried out and did not work?

Comment: Whatever you have tried so far should reflect in your question,I meant the script.

Comment: I tested your XPath and after fixing the HTML to valid XML the result is `500,02`. I fixed the HTML by creating _well-formed_ XML.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sugestion

Comment: Can you provide the site url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
price = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="price"]/@content').extract_first()
ean = response.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="gtin14"]/@content').extract_first()
```